# Using style.php and style.css on wordpress together

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I just finished my theme today and included theme settings page with css.php file where I can change the site colors from panel.

in header I added

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/style.php" />
```

But I want to use it with if else

for example 
if theme is installed and doesnt have changes in theme settings
display
`<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/style.css" />`  css file

But when theme has changes in theme settings page eliminate first css file and display

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/style.php" />
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If I fix this one I will finish my first theme :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add a flag to theme-settings save action. 
For example :

1: In your plugin or theme functions.php

```
add_action( 'optionsframework_after_validate', function(){ // this action is not real, you need to change it to your code
    update_option( 'theme-settings-changed', 'changed' );
});
```

2: In your theme header file

```
$change_check = get_option( 'theme-settings-changed' );
if ( $change_check == 'changed' ) {
?>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/style.php" />
<?php
} else { 
?>
     <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/style.css" />
<?php
}
```

This approach doesn't guarantee if the setting is 'actually' changed because it just checks if the save button is fired regardless of setting changes. But it's a safe bet that the save button would be fired when an user changed a value.
If that's not enough, you can add a check logic for that purpose though it's going to be tedious.

Comment: I think now will work but I get an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'optionsframework_rolescheck' );

function optionsframework_rolescheck () {
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
        // If the user can edit theme options, let the fun begin!
        add_action( 'admin_menu', 'optionsframework_add_page');
        add_action( 'admin_init', 'optionsframework_init' );
        add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'optionsframework_adminbar' );
    }
}

/* Loads the file for option sanitization */

add_action( 'init', 'optionsframework_load_sanitization' );

function optionsframework_load_sanitization() {
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/options-sanitize.php';
}

/* 
 * Creates the settings in the database by looping through the array
 * we supplied in options.php.  This is a neat way to do it since
 * we won't have to save settings for headers, descriptions, or arguments.
 *
 * Read more about the Settings API in the WordPress codex:
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API
 *
 */

function optionsframework_init() {

    // Include the required files
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/options-interface.php';
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/options-media-uploader.php';

    // Optionally Loads the options file from the theme
    $location = apply_filters( 'options_framework_location', array( 'options.php' ) );
    $optionsfile = locate_template( $location );

    // Load settings
    $optionsframework_settings = get_option('optionsframework' );

    // Updates the unique option id in the database if it has changed
    if ( function_exists( 'optionsframework_option_name' ) ) {
        optionsframework_option_name();
    }
    elseif ( has_action( 'optionsframework_option_name' ) ) {
        do_action( 'optionsframework_option_name' );
    }
    // If the developer hasn't explicitly set an option id, we'll use a default
    else {
        $default_themename = get_option( 'stylesheet' );
        $default_themename = preg_replace("/\W/", "_", strtolower($default_themename) );
        $default_themename = 'optionsframework_' . $default_themename;
        if ( isset( $optionsframework_settings['id'] ) ) {
            if ( $optionsframework_settings['id'] == $default_themename ) {
                // All good, using default theme id
            } else {
                $optionsframework_settings['id'] = $default_themename;
                update_option( 'optionsframework', $optionsframework_settings );
            }
        }
        else {
            $optionsframework_settings['id'] = $default_themename;
            update_option( 'optionsframework', $optionsframework_settings );
        }
    }

    // If the option has no saved data, load the defaults
    if ( ! get_option( $optionsframework_settings['id'] ) ) {
        optionsframework_setdefaults();
    }

    // Registers the settings fields and callback
    register_setting( 'optionsframework', $optionsframework_settings['id'], 'optionsframework_validate' );
    // Change the capability required to save the 'optionsframework' options group.
    add_filter( 'option_page_capability_optionsframework', 'optionsframework_page_capability' );
}

/**
 * Ensures that a user with the 'edit_theme_options' capability can actually set the options
 * See: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14365
 *
 * @param string $capability The capability used for the page, which is manage_options by default.
 * @return string The capability to actually use.
 */

function optionsframework_page_capability( $capability ) {
    return 'edit_theme_options';
}

/* 
 * Adds default options to the database if they aren't already present.
 * May update this later to load only on plugin activation, or theme
 * activation since most people won't be editing the options.php
 * on a regular basis.
 *
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option
 *
 */

function optionsframework_setdefaults() {

    $optionsframework_settings = get_option( 'optionsframework' );

    // Gets the unique option id
    $option_name = $optionsframework_settings['id'];

    /* 
     * Each theme will hopefully have a unique id, and all of its options saved
     * as a separate option set.  We need to track all of these option sets so
     * it can be easily deleted if someone wishes to remove the plugin and
     * its associated data.  No need to clutter the database.  
     *
     */

    if ( isset( $optionsframework_settings['knownoptions'] ) ) {
        $knownoptions =  $optionsframework_settings['knownoptions'];
        if ( !in_array( $option_name, $knownoptions ) ) {
            array_push( $knownoptions, $option_name );
            $optionsframework_settings['knownoptions'] = $knownoptions;
            update_option( 'optionsframework', $optionsframework_settings );
        }
    } else {
        $newoptionname = array( $option_name );
        $optionsframework_settings['knownoptions'] = $newoptionname;
        update_option( 'optionsframework', $optionsframework_settings );
    }

    // Gets the default options data from the array in options.php
    $options =& _optionsframework_options();

    // If the options haven't been added to the database yet, they are added now
    $values = of_get_default_values();

    if ( isset( $values ) ) {
        add_option( $option_name, $values ); // Add option with default settings
    }
}


function optionsframework_menu_settings() {

    $menu = array(
        'page_title' => __( 'test Theme Options', 'optionsframework'),
        'menu_title' => __('test Settings', 'optionsframework'),
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'menu_slug' => 'test-options',
        'callback' => 'optionsframework_page'
    );

    return apply_filters( 'optionsframework_menu', $menu );
}

/* Add a subpage called "Theme Options" to the appearance menu. */

function optionsframework_add_page() {

    $menu = optionsframework_menu_settings();
    $of_page = add_theme_page( $menu['page_title'], $menu['menu_title'], $menu['capability'], $menu['menu_slug'], $menu['callback'] );

    // Load the required CSS and javscript
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'optionsframework_load_scripts' );
    add_action( 'admin_print_styles-' . $of_page, 'optionsframework_load_styles' );
}

/* Loads the CSS */

function optionsframework_load_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'optionsframework', OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY.'css/optionsframework.css' );
    if ( !wp_style_is( 'wp-color-picker','registered' ) ) {
        wp_register_style( 'wp-color-picker', OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY.'css/color-picker.min.css' );
    }
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
}

/* Loads the javascript */

function optionsframework_load_scripts( $hook ) {

    $menu = optionsframework_menu_settings();

    if ( 'appearance_page_' . $menu['menu_slug'] != $hook )
        return;

    // Enqueue colorpicker scripts for versions below 3.5 for compatibility
    if ( !wp_script_is( 'wp-color-picker', 'registered' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'iris', false, array( 'jquery','jquery-ui-draggable', 'jquery-ui-slider', 'jquery-touch-punch' ), false, 1 );
        wp_register_script( 'wp-color-picker', OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY . 'js/color-picker.min.js', array( 'jquery', 'iris' ) );
        $colorpicker_l10n = array(
            'clear' => __( 'Clear','options_framework_theme' ),
            'defaultString' => __( 'Default', 'options_framework_theme' ),
            'pick' => __( 'Select Color', 'options_framework_theme' )
        );
        wp_localize_script( 'wp-color-picker', 'wpColorPickerL10n', $colorpicker_l10n );
    }

    // Enqueue custom option panel JS
    wp_enqueue_script( 'options-custom', OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY . 'js/options-custom.js', array( 'jquery','wp-color-picker' ) );

    // Inline scripts from options-interface.php
    add_action( 'admin_head', 'of_admin_head' );
}

function of_admin_head() {
    // Hook to add custom scripts
    do_action( 'optionsframework_custom_scripts' );
}

/* 
 * Builds out the options panel.
 *
 * If we were using the Settings API as it was likely intended we would use
 * do_settings_sections here.  But as we don't want the settings wrapped in a table,
 * we'll call our own custom optionsframework_fields.  See options-interface.php
 * for specifics on how each individual field is generated.
 *
 * Nonces are provided using the settings_fields()
 *
 */

if ( !function_exists( 'optionsframework_page' ) ) :
function optionsframework_page() {
    settings_errors(); ?>

    <div id="optionsframework-wrap" class="wrap">
    <?php screen_icon( 'themes' ); ?>
    <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
        <?php echo optionsframework_tabs(); ?>
    </h2>

    <div id="optionsframework-metabox" class="metabox-holder">
        <div id="optionsframework" class="postbox">
            <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php settings_fields( 'optionsframework' ); ?>
            <?php optionsframework_fields(); /* Settings */ ?>
            <div id="optionsframework-submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" name="update" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save Options', 'options_framework_theme' ); ?>" />
                <input type="submit" class="reset-button button-secondary" name="reset" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Restore Defaults', 'options_framework_theme' ); ?>" onclick="return confirm( '<?php print esc_js( __( 'Click OK to reset. Any theme settings will be lost!', 'options_framework_theme' ) ); ?>' );" />
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div> <!-- / #container -->
    </div>
    <?php do_action( 'optionsframework_after' ); ?>
    </div> <!-- / .wrap -->

<?php
}
endif;

/**
 * Validate Options.
 *
 * This runs after the submit/reset button has been clicked and
 * validates the inputs.
 *
 * @uses $_POST['reset'] to restore default options
 */
function optionsframework_validate( $input ) {

    /*
     * Restore Defaults.
     *
     * In the event that the user clicked the "Restore Defaults"
     * button, the options defined in the theme's options.php
     * file will be added to the option for the active theme.
     */

    if ( isset( $_POST['reset'] ) ) {
        add_settings_error( 'options-framework', 'restore_defaults', __( 'Default options restored.', 'options_framework_theme' ), 'updated fade' );
        return of_get_default_values();
    }

    /*
     * Update Settings
     *
     * This used to check for $_POST['update'], but has been updated
     * to be compatible with the theme customizer introduced in WordPress 3.4
     */

    $clean = array();
    $options =& _optionsframework_options();
    foreach ( $options as $option ) {

        if ( ! isset( $option['id'] ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ( ! isset( $option['type'] ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $id = preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9._\-]/', '', strtolower( $option['id'] ) );

        // Set checkbox to false if it wasn't sent in the $_POST
        if ( 'checkbox' == $option['type'] && ! isset( $input[$id] ) ) {
            $input[$id] = false;
        }

        // Set each item in the multicheck to false if it wasn't sent in the $_POST
        if ( 'multicheck' == $option['type'] && ! isset( $input[$id] ) ) {
            foreach ( $option['options'] as $key => $value ) {
                $input[$id][$key] = false;
            }
        }

        // For a value to be submitted to database it must pass through a sanitization filter
        if ( has_filter( 'of_sanitize_' . $option['type'] ) ) {
            $clean[$id] = apply_filters( 'of_sanitize_' . $option['type'], $input[$id], $option );
        }
    }

    // Hook to run after validation
    do_action( 'optionsframework_after_validate', $clean );

    return $clean;
}

/**
 * Display message when options have been saved
 */

function optionsframework_save_options_notice() {
    add_settings_error( 'options-framework', 'save_options', __( 'Options saved.', 'options_framework_theme' ), 'updated fade' );
}

add_action( 'optionsframework_after_validate', 'optionsframework_save_options_notice' );

/**
 * Format Configuration Array.
 *
 * Get an array of all default values as set in
 * options.php. The 'id','std' and 'type' keys need
 * to be defined in the configuration array. In the
 * event that these keys are not present the option
 * will not be included in this function's output.
 *
 * @return    array     Rey-keyed options configuration array.
 *
 * @access    private
 */

function of_get_default_values() {
    $output = array();
    $config =& _optionsframework_options();
    foreach ( (array) $config as $option ) {
        if ( ! isset( $option['id'] ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        if ( ! isset( $option['std'] ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        if ( ! isset( $option['type'] ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        if ( has_filter( 'of_sanitize_' . $option['type'] ) ) {
            $output[$option['id']] = apply_filters( 'of_sanitize_' . $option['type'], $option['std'], $option );
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

/**
 * Add Theme Options menu item to Admin Bar.
 */


function &_optionsframework_options() {
    static $options = null;

    if ( !$options ) {
        // Load options from options.php file (if it exists)
        $location = apply_filters( 'options_framework_location', array('options.php') );
        if ( $optionsfile = locate_template( $location ) ) {
            $maybe_options = require_once $optionsfile;
            if ( is_array($maybe_options) ) {
                $options = $maybe_options;
            } else if ( function_exists( 'optionsframework_options' ) ) {
                $options = optionsframework_options();
            }
        }

        // Allow setting/manipulating options via filters
        $options = apply_filters('of_options', $options);
    }

    return $options;
}

/**
 * Get Option.
 *
 * Helper function to return the theme option value.
 * If no value has been saved, it returns $default.
 * Needed because options are saved as serialized strings.
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 'of_get_option' ) ) {

    function of_get_option( $name, $default = false ) {
        $config = get_option( 'optionsframework' );

        if ( ! isset( $config['id'] ) ) {
            return $default;
        }

        $options = get_option( $config['id'] );

        if ( isset( $options[$name] ) ) {
            return $options[$name];
        }

        return $default;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the name of the file?
And if it's not options.php, post the code of options.php too

Answer (score 0):

```
function optionsframework_option_name() {

    // This gets the theme name from the stylesheet
    $themename = wp_get_theme();
    $themename = preg_replace("/\W/", "_", strtolower($themename) );

    $optionsframework_settings = get_option( 'optionsframework' );
    $optionsframework_settings['id'] = $themename;
    update_option( 'optionsframework', $optionsframework_settings );
}

/**
 * Defines an array of options that will be used to generate the settings page and be saved in the database.
 * When creating the 'id' fields, make sure to use all lowercase and no spaces.
 *
 * If you are making your theme translatable, you should replace 'test'
 * with the actual text domain for your theme.  Read more:
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain
 */

function optionsframework_options() {

    $options = array();
    $imagepath =  get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/';    
    $true_false = array(
        'true' => __('true', 'test'),
        'false' => __('false', 'test')
    );      

   $options[] = array(
    'name' => __('General', 'test'),
    'type' => 'heading');

    $options[] = array(
        'name' => __('Site Links', 'test'),
        'desc' => __('Site Links color', 'test'),
        'id' => 'links',
        'std' => '',
        'class' => '',
        'type' => 'color');

    $options[] = array(
        'name' => __('Site Links Hover', 'test'),
        'desc' => __('Site Links Hover color', 'test'),
        'id' => 'hover',
        'std' => '',
        'class' => '',
        'type' => 'color');                 

    $options[] = array(
        'name' => __('Background Color', 'test'),
        'desc' => __('background color', 'test'),
        'id' => 'bg',
        'std' => '',
        'class' => '',
        'type' => 'color');                                             

    return $options;
}
```